# Apache Camel Multiple SQL Statements

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am getting a message that contains various stuff in it. From that message I generate multiple SQL statements and add them in a list. In my previous implementation it was not a problem and I was executing the statements one by one but I could not find whether it is possible or not doing the same thing with apache camel. Simply what I'm asking is, is it possible to execute multiple SQL statements with apache camel?

Something like below?
PS: Each statement is different from each other usually.

```
`from(...).process(new Processor()).to(THIS IS WHERE MULTIPLE STATEMENTS GOES I ASSUME)`
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Recipient List EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/recipientList-eip.html) to set list of target endpoints dynamically at run-time.

Slightly modify your `Processor` and prepare `List` of endpoints to header.

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("MyListOfStatements", Arrays.asList(
    "sql:INSERT something INTO somewhere", 
    "sql:INSERT anything INTO elsewhere"
));
```

Then use this header as `Expression` in `recipientList`

```
from(...).process(new Processor()).recipientList(header("MyListOfStatements"));
```

Comment: Worked just fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the camel loop eip and each loop you can use the loop index to fetch the sql statement from the list and execute it.